# Magento Product rating display summery of single review

Tags: php, magento

I use 5 rating options for a product review.
It is displayed as below.

[image]

But I want to also display the total score of that review. 
A score that display the average score of the total 5 of that score.

*(I do not want to display the average of all reviews, only the average of each individual review)*

New code with review summary code:

```
<?php $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review') ->getResourceCollection() ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())  ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED) ->setDateOrder() ->addRateVotes();
$avg = 0; $totalrv = 0; $totalrvper =0; $ratings = array();
if (count($reviews) > 0) { foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) { foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) { $totalrv = $totalrv +$vote->getValue(); $totalrvper = $totalrvper + $vote->getPercent(); }
} $totalrv= ($totalrv/3)/4; $totalrvper = ($totalrvper/3)/4; $avgrate = round($totalrv, 1); } ?>

        <div class="summaryrating">
            <div class="categoryratings-header" style="display: none;">
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            </div>
            <span class="reviewratingstars">            
                <div class="rating-box" style="padding-bottom: 34px;">
                    <div style="width:<?php echo $totalrvper; ?>%;" class="rating"></div>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span class="showcategoryratings" id="showcategoryratings-header">
                <span class="showcategoryratings-text" title="Bekijk de beoordelingen per categorie">Per categorie</span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

This is my detailed.phtml

```
    <?php $_votes = $this->getRatingVotes($_review->getId());?>
    <?php if (count($_votes)): ?>
    <table class="ratings-table">
        <col width="1" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $_vote->getRatingCode() ?></th>
                <td>
                    <div class="rating-box">
                        <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I display this?

**EDIT TO DISPLAY SINGLE REVIEW SUMMARY:**

```
    <div class="ratingstars">
            <h4 class="title-beoordeling">Beoordeling</h4>
            <ul class="ratingbox">
            <?php foreach ($this->getRating() as $_rating): ?>
                <?php if($_rating->getPercent()): ?>
                     <li>
                        <span class="ratingcategoryname"><?php echo $this->__($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></span>
                        <span class="reviewratingstars">
                            <div class="rating-score sum">
                                <div class="score-rating" style="width:<?php echo ceil($_rating->getPercent()) ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
        <?php $summary += $_vote->getPercent(); ?>
        <?php $total++ ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
                     <li class="averagerating">
                        <span class="ratingcategoryname">Gemiddelde beoordeling</span>
                        <span class="reviewratingstars">
                            <div class="rating-score sum">
                                <div class="score-rating" style="width:<?php echo $summary/$total ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                   </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review') ->getResourceCollection() ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) ->addEntityFilter('product', Mage::registry('current_product')->getId()) ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED) ->setDateOrder() ->addRateVotes();
$avg = 0; $avgper = 0; $totalrv = 0; $totalrvper =0; $ratings = array(); $count = 0;
if (count($reviews) > 0) { foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) { foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) { $totalrv = $totalrv +$vote->getValue(); $count++; $totalrvper = $totalrvper + $vote->getPercent(); }
} $avg= $totalrv/count($reviews); $avgper = round($totalrvper/$count ,1);} ?>
        <div class="summaryrating">
            <div class="categoryratings-header" style="display: none;">
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            </div>
            <span class="reviewratingstars">

                <div class="rating-box" style="padding-bottom: 34px;">
                    <div style="width:<?php echo $avgper; ?>%;" class="rating"></div>
                </div>
            </span>
            <span class="showcategoryratings" id="showcategoryratings-header">
                <span class="showcategoryratings-text" title="Bekijk de beoordelingen per categorie">Per categorie</span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: That does not show a review summary. That display the total review with all rating stars. I want the summary of that review.

Comment: you want the average of design + snelheid + ... ?

Comment: Yes, I want the average of all five the values. So the single review average. Just like the Reviews-summery that displays the average of all reviews. But in this case I want the average of each single review.

Comment: Kaes, the displayed data does not refresh. When I delete a review, than the average score is not updated. How can I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean by deleting ? From admin review management? If you have an url to watch your website it coulds help :D

Comment: I update mine too, How do you got the color on your post?  Mine just look like a big pile of code :(

Comment: Tried your new code, but that does not load the page anymore. You can use the colors by placing the code between this: ` enter code here `

Comment: oh crap, just a blank page?

Comment: Yes indeed, just a blank page from the place where it loads the php code.

Comment: Could you enable error displaying on index.php (root directory) by uncommenting `        ini_set('display_errors', 1);    `

Comment: Does your code display the average score of the product or the average score of all products? Because your code also display the average score on a product, that does not even have a review.

Comment: per product, because your code (edited last time) was displaying for all products (no filter in get collection)

Comment: Is the average review empty when the products doesn't have a review?

Comment: No because it is still displaying a blank page. I get this error: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /template/reviews/view.phtml on line 9

Comment: Yes at multiple places.

Comment: Do you know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Wooops sorry, I have forgotten you! Could you paste your URL again please, with the code I've provided you on your website?

Comment: The old code yes, not the new code. Because that breaks down the page.

Comment: Could you use the new one, but with error displaying enabled?

Comment: instead of ` $_product->getId() ` could you use ` Mage::registry('current_product')->getId() `

Comment: I tried that, but then all stars are filled. Thats not the right average score.

Comment: I know why, I wasn't counting the vote, only the reviews. Now with the updated answer, it shoulds work

Comment: What is the code to display the average score of a review individually?

Comment: No I want to display the average score of each individual review. We use 5 rating options for each review, and I want to display the average score of those 5 rating options per review.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection()->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->addEntityFilter('product', Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)->setDateOrder()->addRateVotes();
$avgper = 0;
$totalrvper = 0;
$ratings = array();
$count = 0;
$totalcount = 0;
if (count($reviews) > 0) {
foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
    foreach ($review->getRatingVotes() as $vote) {
        $totalcount++;
        $totalrvper = $totalrvper + $vote->getPercent();
        $ratings[$vote->getCode()]["count"] = $ratings[$vote->getCode()]["count"] + 1;
        $ratings[$vote->getCode()]["avg"] = $ratings[$vote->getCode()]["avg"] + $vote->getPercent();
    }
}
$avgper = round($totalrvper / $totalcount, 1);}?>
<div class="summaryrating">
<div class="categoryratings-header" style="display: none;">
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true) ?>
</div>
<span class="reviewratingstars">

    <div class="rating-box" style="padding-bottom: 34px;">
        <div style="width:<?php echo $avgper; ?>%;" class="rating"></div>
    </div>
</span>
<span class="showcategoryratings" id="showcategoryratings-header">
    <span class="showcategoryratings-text" title="Bekijk de beoordelingen per categorie">Per categorie</span>
</span>
<span class="reviewperratingstars">
<?php foreach($ratings as $code => $rating) : ?>
    <div class="rating-box" style="padding-bottom: 34px;">
        <span class="label"><?php echo $code ?></span>
        <span style="width:<?php echo round($rating["avg"]/$rating["count"],1); ?>%;" class="rating"></span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</span>
```

`

Comment: thanks. Tried your code but that did not work. See my current code in my question.